# How to check memory usage of the current instance from within the code

Tags: python, google-app-engine, memory-management

I plan to write big(size could go up from few kBs to hundreds of MB) files to GCS using GAE Python GCS Client library.  I would be building up the content to write to a file in iterations. This content is stored in a variable(say, `"X"`) which gets concatenated with more content in each iteration of the loop. After each iteration, I want to check the current memory usage of my code so that I can stop adding more memory.  If I keep on adding more content to that variable(`"X"`), I foresee that I could hit the memory limit and the instance might even shut down in a non graceful manner. 
I want to stop the iterations once the memory limit is being reached.

How to check memory usage of the current instance of my app within the code?

I am not using Backends or Modules. Can [GAE Python Runtime API](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/backends/runtimeapi) be used for this?  If yes, is that API deprecated?

**Sample Code**

```
SAFE_MARGIN = 10 
INSTANCE_MEMORY_LIMIT = 128 

content = "" 
for record in record_list: 
    content = content + record.description 
    if ((memory_usage + SAFE_MARGIN) >= INSTANCE_MEMORY_LIMIT): # CHECK IF MEMORY LIMIT IS REACHED HERE 
        break # STOP ADDING MORE 
# WRITE FILE TO GCS HERE (value of "content" variable)
```

**UPDATE**
Since I did not get any reply and could not find anything in Google documentation, I have raised a [new Feature Request with Google](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=11141).

Answer (score 1):

You can use Python Runtime API to check on the memory usage of both frontend and backend instances:

```
from google.appengine.api.runtime import memory_usage

SAFE_MARGIN = 10 
INSTANCE_MEMORY_LIMIT = 128 

content = "" 
for record in record_list: 
    content = content + record.description 
    if ((int(memory_usage().current() + SAFE_MARGIN) >= INSTANCE_MEMORY_LIMIT): # CHECK IF MEMORY LIMIT IS REACHED HERE 
        break # STOP ADDING MORE 
# WRITE FILE TO GCS HERE (value of "content" variable)
```

But if you're often running out of memory, consider upgrading the instance class...

Comment: FYI, this API has been deprecated and since 2013.  I just noticed it started giving me errors, so I'm not sure it's a good idea to use it.